# Foundation 6 and Rails not rendering correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to display the Foundation 6 nav bar but have not been able to get the html to render correctly. I have followed the Foundation docs to set up the project but have not been able to get anything to work. Here is a screen shot of the errors that I can get in the console when I try to preview the page.

[Screen shot of console errors](https://www.dropbox.com/s/posg1cfg6k8ocho/Screen%20Shot%202016-07-17%20at%2011.25.09%20AM.png?dl=0)

I am rather new to using Foundation.

### Update

The nav bar I was using from the Zurb building blocks had some sort error. I switched to a different nav and now everything works.

Comment: Given the solution, I think this can be put on hold as "typo / no repro" for now.